# Mysqldump syntax error

Tags: mysql, dump

I'm currently trying to execute a dump on mysql schema, but it keeps showing a message of sql syntax.

The command that I'm using is:

```
mysqldump -u root -p password "logicstore" > "c:\backup.sql";
```

Is that a punctuation issue or something like that?

PS: I've already tried different syntaxes. I've seen on others questions like these.

Comment: Hi Joao - can you paste in _exactly_ what error message it returns? Without that, it's hard to know what might be going wrong. Remember - on Stack Overflow all users are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit questions, to improve them as much as possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: mysqldump is not an SQL command, you have to run it in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set password in command line. And it is much more safe to use `-r` instead of pipe...

```
mysqldump -u root -p <database_name> -r <file_name>
```

If you want to use it without asking for password, you have to edit cardinals in `.my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqldump]
user=root
password=<password>
```